# Change in file does not commit

Tags: gnome-terminal

I am editing the file `wmem_max` from `/proc/sys/net/core` using the command:

```
echo 83886080 > /proc/sys/net/core/wmem_max
```

The value in the file changes, but when I restart the machine, the value reverts back to its old value. Why does the value I set not commit? Is there anymore command to commit the changes?

Comment: Is there a default value being set from `/etc/sysctl.conf`, or a file under `/etc/sysctl.d`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add these values to the end of your `/etc/sysctl.conf` file, or create a file under `/etc/sysctl.d`. There are plenty of examples online, but this file is loaded with every boot, so the values are reloaded everytime. The values are most likely defaulted in the kernel config, so you need to reload them.

If you want to load them during the current boot without rebooting, just do: `sysctl -p` after your changes, and they will take effect immediately. Here is just one page I found quickly on setting these values: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-251509.html

Hope this helps.